# How To Customize Ubuntu Bash to make it like Mint?

Tags: bash, customization, mint

I love Linux Mint's bash customization. It includes both a color prompt and a quote displayed with ASCII art.

Is it possible to have it in Ubuntu?

Comment: You might want to describe what these customizations are. It's most likely possible in Ubuntu, but you need to tell us what you're looking for.

Comment: attach a picture please...

Comment: It's not easy to show with a picture...
It has different colours and random ascii art and quote at each time you open the terminal...

Comment: Look in files like `.bashrc` on Mint.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The file `~/.bashrc` allows you to make the customizations you would like, among other things.

First open it with `gedit ~/.bashrc`

Now in order to have the multicolored prompt, find the line that looks like this:

`#force_color_prompt=yes`

Un-comment it (remove the `#`).

Now to get the ascii art and quote, you will need to install two packages:

`sudo apt-get install cowsay fortune`

Now in `~/.bashrc` add a line with:

`fortune | cowsay`

Save the file, and restart your terminal (or resource the file with `source ~/.bashrc`).

[image: mint-like bash prompt]

Comment: And change the background color to white as well. That's how it is in Mint.

Answer (score 3):

The custom setup is done in `/etc/bash.bashrc` on Linux Mint 11 - if you download the .iso you can mount that as a loop device on Ubuntu and copy/paste the text, which is quite large, but you should be able to paste it into your `~/.bashrc`.

One nice feature is that the prompt changes to red when you are root.

There will also be some setup for the GNOME Terminal application to make the background be white - you can do that through the Terminal preferences.

Comment: Brilliant! :)  :)

Answer (score 1):

If add the following to your [.bashrc file](http://www.vsubhash.com/article.asp?id=13&info=Ubuntu_and_Gnome_Diary#change_terminal_prompt), you get color-coded date, time, username, hostname, and the current directory. Most importantly, you get the entire line to type your command.

```
PS1="\a\n\n\e[31;1m\u@\h on \d at \@\n\e[33;1m\w\e[0m\n$ "
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of customizing `~/bashrc` file manually, simply use [Gogh](https://github.com/Mayccoll/Gogh) script for the customization of the entire color scheme for `Gnome` terminal.

The Gogh library provides dozens of different color schemes which can be installed by simply running a single command and restarting the terminal.

For instance, the following command will change the color scheme to light,

```
wget -O xt  http://git.io/vs7UQ && chmod +x xt && ./xt && rm xt
```

**DEMO**

[image]

Please visit on the following page for the list of all the available Color Schemes and their demonstration,

https://github.com/Mayccoll/Gogh/blob/master/content/themes.md

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible. Just open up your .bashrc file with any Editor(ex: nano, vi and etc.).Then scroll down to this line of code.

`if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '...........`

Then comment out the current PS1 variable (If you want to use it later).Then add Mint prompt instead of that. Just paste this right below that.

`PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\]$ '`

Then save it and reopen up the terminal. You'll see the changes.

#### Have you seen the bash prompt of parrot os??

I found it very cool.I have uploaded bash prompts for both root and normal users in Linux Mint to my Github account. Here's the [link](https://github.com/ChathuraDR/Parrot-bash-prompt-For-Mint) to my repo. I have added the screenshots there. Just like first modification, now use the following variable instead.

`PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;35m\]\[\033[0;35m\]\342\224\214\342\224\200\$([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \"[\[\033[0;35m\]\342\234\227\[\033[0;37m\]]\342\224\200\")[$(if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then echo '\[\033[01;35m\]root\[\033[01;33m\]@\[\033[01;96m\]\h'; else echo '\[\033[0;39m\]\u\[\033[01;33m\]@\[\033[01;96m\]\h'; fi)\[\033[0;35m\]]\342\224\200[\[\033[01;32m\]\w\[\033[0;35m\]]\n\[\033[0;35m\]\342\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\200\342\225\274 \[\033[0m\]\[\e[01;33m\]\\$\[\e[0m\] "`

Reopen up the terminal, then you'll see [this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikswc.png)
Hope you found this answer useful.